# Lync, skype & msn in a WCF service

Tags: wcf, skype, lync

I have a WCF service allowing users to connect to different protocols accounts (like Yahoo)
I'm now interested in adding a "microsoft" feature to this WCF, so users can connect to their msn/skype/lync account.

I've searched online and found good infos on how lync and LCS don't work together, but nothing really clear about the microsoft plans of regrouping APIs.  (now that the own Skype)

2 questions:

I] Is there something I've missed (like a nice unified microsoft API) or should i really use different & separate APIs?
(skype API mentions: The Skype Public API is no longer being improved, although it is still being maintained)

II] Lync API needs Lync client to be install on the computer: it re-uses the lync server connection. I'm afraid i'll have problems if I try to implement it on a WCF. (multiple connection, authorization, disconnection of the "real" client if he uses lync in his Outlook)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont know about all questions, but Lync definately allows multiple connections for a single user. I'm using a trusted server application (in a hosted service) in which I create user endpoints for people connecting through the service. This has no impact on any other connections a user might have.